How to change the color of selected item(s) in custom series
Taking the documented example for custom series rendering 'rect' elements, how can I let the color change when an item is selected?
The 1st step is of course to add selectedMode: "single", but then I am stuck.
I tried adding this:
select: {
  itemStyle: {
    color: "#4338ca",
  },
},
emphasis: {
  itemStyle: {
    color: "#be123c",
  },
},

but it does not seem to be taken into account (see the modified example).
Bonus related question: the api.style() method is flagged as deprecated when I use it in VS Code or the online editor, but there is no such deprecation mentioned in the user docs?

You have to define the behaviour for select and emphasis inside the renderItem function.
Example:
renderItem: function (params, api) {

    ...

    return {
        type: 'rect',
        shape: { ... },
        style: { ... },
        select: {
            style: { fill: '#4338ca' }
        },
        emphasis: {
            style: { fill: '#be123c' }
        }
    };
}

The documentation is not maintained perfectly, often times there is information missing or its not quite correct.

Thank you!!  I had tried something similar but I had configured select.itemStyle.color instead of select.style.fill (which makes sense now that I think about it, as we are down to SVG spec level here).
